# Sql server syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello for some reason my sql server script is giving me an syntax error although the code worked before and i have no idea why i am new to sql and have looked online but have found nothing that will fix it. the user_id is pink for some reason and the grade_recieved is giving me an error.

```
create table exam(
    exam_id varchar (10) not null,
    user_id varchar (10) not null,
    location varchar (30) not null,
    date_taken varchar (8) not null,
    exam_taken varchar (20) not null
    grade_recieved varchar (4) not null,
    primary key (exam_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES account (user_id)
   );
```

Comment: Your missing a `,` before the column `grade_recieved`

Comment: If you get in the habit of putting your commas at the start of the line instead of the end, these mistakes will happen less frequently and be easier to spot.

Comment: Also `grade_received` not `grade_recieved`

Answer (score 6):

A comma is missing before the `grade_recieved`, at the end of the `exam_taken` line:

```
CREATE TABLE exam
(
    exam_id            VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
   ,USER_ID            VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
   ,location           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
   ,date_taken         VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
   ,exam_taken         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
   ,grade_recieved     VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
   ,PRIMARY KEY(exam_id)
   ,FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES account(USER_ID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks thats it sorted